# Remove inline styles from django-tinymce html content

Tags: html, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

When I save content through django-tinymce it adds its own inline styles. However I'd like to remove this behaviour and just save the content in plain html. Can you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use any of tinyMCE configs like this:**

**Put this to your Django settings.py**
(this will tell tinyMCE which elements are allowed`)

**DJANGO settings.py**

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "advanced",
    'valid_elements' : 'a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br,p'
}
```

**And push Clean Button in TinyMCE**.

**All TinyMCE configs** [is here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements):

Try also look at `invalid_elements` and `invalid_styles`

P.S. It would have more sense to set:

`'invalid_elements': 'p[styles], span'`

to remove all styles But It didn't work.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your own implementation of a save function using

`getContent({format: 'text'})`

I'm no Djanjo expert but it sounds like the problem is being caused by them, and not TinyMCE itself.